# How to return image file using custom route to cache the image file?

Tags: c#, caching, routes, asp.net-mvc

I'm having a hard time figuring out on how to cache the image from a blob stream.
This is my first code and it works to download the return the image file:

**HTML PART:**

```
<img src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Asset")?photoId=@SessionData.ProfilePic.PhotoID&type=3"/>
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
public ActionResult GetImage(long photoId, PhotoType type)
{   
    byte[] img = <Code that fetches image byte from blob stream>;
    return File(img, "image/png");            
}
```

But this fail to cache in browser.
I am thinking that if the url seems to be like this:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/Asset/GetImage/1/2
```

the image can now be cache?
So I create another route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Upload",
    "Asset/GetImage/{photoId}/{type}",
    new { controller = "Asset", action = "GetImage" }
);
```

and access the image like this:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/Asset/GetImage/1/2
<img src="http://stackoverflow.com/Asset/GetImage/1/2" />
```

But I always get:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Now my questions are:

1. Am I right of thinking that when the url is formatted like this `http://stackoverflow.com/Asset/GetImage/1/2` it can now be cache by the browser?
2. Why do I get this error? `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` What's wrong with my route?

Hope someone could help.

**EDIT**

This is my full Routes:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
    "Upload",
    "Asset/GetImage/{photoId}/{type}",
    new { controller = "Asset", action = "GetImage" }
);

var route = routes.MapRoute(
        "Gallery",
        "",
        new { controller = "Auth", action = "Login" },
        new[] { "Project.Areas.Gallery.Controllers" }
    );

route.DataTokens["area"] = "Gallery";
```

And still getting the error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` , what could be wrong ?

**EDIT2**

The list of meta tags I've used:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="false">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: Regarding the caching have you tried the OutputCache attirbute against the controller action methods? http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. But no luck.

Comment: Does it work when you access the image directly? ie using http://yourserver/Asset/GetImage/1/2

Comment: No. Because the params`(1/2)` are keys to reference from database, then used to download the image byte from blob via stream. There is not direct link to the image file.

Comment: I think it should work - I've created a simple example using your example code and both direct url and image tag work - even by adding OutputCache attribute I can confirm caching now works

Comment: So can you confirm that an exception isn't being thrown from your controller method GetImage?

Comment: Can I see your headers? I'm trying again the OutpuCache. My headers look like this: Cache-Control: no-cache, Expires: -1, Pragma: no-cache. This is the code: [OutputCache(Duration = 10)]

Comment: @ChrisMoutray There is no any exception thrown. I'm putting break points in every block of code and didn't encounter any error.

Comment: From what I can tell 404 are common when routes don't match but you've said that breakpoint is hit within the GetImage method.

Comment: Sorry to confuse you, I put break points on GetImage Action method, I don't get any error because it doesn't even pass the break point. Please see my edit. Thanks!

Comment: Still a little confused your edit to the question and comments here say your GetImage isn't working, but against my answer your comments suggest it is work just that the cache isn't working ie every request to /Asset/GetImage/#/# goes through your GetImage action method - can you clarify? Thanks.

Comment: I manage to make the link work. Now my problem is the caching. The image is not being cached. I wonder how you did it successfully while we have the same code, `[OutputCache(Duration = 20, VaryByParam = "photoId")]`. Thanks

Comment: See edit to answer - can you comment on the whether you've tried to disable caching somewhere? If remove the attribute i see `Cache-Control: private` in the header and not `Cache-Control: no-cache`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me

**Action Method**

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 20, VaryByParam = "photoId")]
public ActionResult GetImage(long photoId, long type)
{
    byte[] img = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/Images/aspNetHome.png"));
    return File(img, "image/png");
}
```

**HTML**

```
<img src="~/Home/GetImage/1/2" alt="" />
```

**Route added to Global asax**

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Upload",
    "Home/GetImage/{photoId}/{type}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "GetImage" }
);
```

**Response headers from Fiddler**

> Referer: http:// localhost /MvcApplicationImageTest/Home/GetImage/1/2*

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, max-age=20
Content-Type: image/png
Expires: Wed, 01 Aug 2012 05:08:25 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 01 Aug 2012 05:08:05 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 4.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 01 Aug 2012 05:08:10 GMT
Content-Length: 3736
```

**EDIT following comments**

**OutputCacheAttribute removed**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: image/png
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 4.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 02 Aug 2012 04:52:02 GMT
Content-Length: 3736
```

As you can see in the headers, `Cache-Control` just shows `private` and not `Cache-Control: no-cache, Expires: -1, Pragma: no-cache`

I now believe you must be explicitly disabling the cache somehow? Do you have any *META* tags in your view or layout pages? eg

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />

<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />

<meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1" />
```

Comment: if I use this link: `<img src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Asset")?photoId=@SessionData.ProfilePic.PhotoID&type=3"/>` then I am now able to download the byte[]. But still even if I put your code: `[OutputCache(Duration = 20, VaryByParam = "photoId")]` it is not cached. Fiddler gives this result: Cache-Control: no-cache, Expires: -1, Pragma: no-cache

Comment: I have managed to make the link work: `<img src="~/Asset/GetImage/1/2" alt="" />` but still the image is not cached. Please help. thanks

Comment: No reason to read all the bytes into your code, just use this instead: `return new FilePathResult(Server.MapPath("~/Images/aspNetHome.png"), "image/png");`

Comment: Sure, but it's always good to suggest improvements in general I think.

Comment: @SteenT actually `Controller.File` has an overload that accepts a file path http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187261/whats-the-difference-between-the-four-file-results-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: @ChrisMoutray I have listed all meta tags that I use. Please see my **EDIT2**

Comment: @ChrisMoutray I voted up your answer since your code works on new mvc project. But still I can't figure out why it doesn't work on the real one. Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: @fiberOptics its difficult to tell whats wrong with your original project - there must be other config somewhere eg web.config or in the global.ascx

Comment: What can i do when i use remote url like cdn?

Comment: @CanÜrek I think you need to look at cdn provider to see if there are any cache options. Or you somehow route the cdn url through your api but that would defeat the point of the cdn - so I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I handle it like that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164333/asp-net-mvc-returning-a-cdn-images-from-controller