# MVC4 C# - Want to save a image to a folder and saving the url in database

Tags: c#, database, image, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm pretty new with MVC4 coding. Have been programming in SharePoint before.

The issue i have is that i want to save a image to a specific folder (Let say App_Data) and also save the url of the image to a string in a database. 
Would be great if anyone could help me with this issue.

The code i got right now is.

Models > ImageUpload.cs

```
public class ImageUpload

{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; } 
    public string Url { get; set; }
}

public class ImageUploadDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ImageUpload> ImageUploads { get; set; }
}
```

Controllers > ImageUploadController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(ImageUpload imageupload)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.ImageUploads.Add(imageupload);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(imageupload);
    }

[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase[] files)
    {
        foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files)
        {
            string picture = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), picture);
            string[] paths = path.Split('.');
            string time = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString();
            time = time.Replace(" ", "-");
            time = time.Replace(":", "-"); 
            file.SaveAs(paths[0] + "-" + time + ".jpg");
        }
        ViewBag.Message = "File(s) uploaded successfully";
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

View > ImageUpload > Index.cshtml

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Url)
        </th>
        <th>
            Preview
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Url)
            </td>
            <td>
                <img border="0" src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Url)" alt="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)">
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
            </td>
        </tr>    
    }
</table>
```

View > ImageUpload > Create.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>ImageUpload</legend>

            @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        <b>@Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.Title)</b>
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.Title)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.Title)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        <b>@Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.Url)</b>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        @Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.Url)
                        <input type="file" name="files" value="" multiple="multiple"/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                    </div>
            }


    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't bother saving the image to the `App_Data` folder as if you are storing the url to it, it won't be accessible via the web.

Comment: Why do you have separate Create and Upload methods when it seems like it can do the whole thing in one go?

Comment: storing image binary in DB is a better option..

Answer (score 1):

For file uploading, you can use this code. Image saved to folder and filename stored to database:

In controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(EventModel eventmodel, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{ 
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      var filename = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
      var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/Photo/"), filename);
      file.SaveAs(path);
      tyre.Url = filename;

      _db.EventModels.AddObject(eventmodel);
      _db.SaveChanges();
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
   }
   return View(eventmodel);
}
```

And View:

```
<div>
   Image
   <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
   @Html.HiddenFor( model => model.ImageUrl)
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor( model => model.Url )
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine the two methods into one method logic, code should be like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase[] files)
    {
        // try to save the file
        foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files)
        {
            string picture = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), picture);
            string[] paths = path.Split('.');
            string time = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString();
            time = time.Replace(" ", "-");
            time = time.Replace(":", "-"); 
            file.SaveAs(paths[0] + "-" + time + ".jpg");
        }

        // try to save the new file name to db now.
        try
        {
            db.ImageUploads.Add(paths[0] + time + ".jpg");
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
             ..........
        }

        ViewBag.Message = "File(s) uploaded successfully";
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller action you need to perform an HTTP request to fetch the image from the remote server:

```
public ActionResult Thumb(int id)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        byte[] image = client.DownloadData("http://cdn.foo.com/myimage.jpg");
        return File(image, "image/jpg");
    }
}
```

and then:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("Thumb")" alt="" />
```

Obviously now the image is downloaded twice. Once in the controller from the CDN and once from the client. This completely defeats the purpose of this controller action and you could directly reference the image from the CDN:

```
<img src="http://cdn.foo.com/myimage.jpg" alt="" />
```

This obviously assumes that the client has access to the CDN.

Of course if your controller action does more than just fetching an image from a CDN and streaming it to the client like for example fetching the image from a CDN and resizing it, then you should definitely take the first approach.

sources from:[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164333/asp-net-mvc-returning-a-cdn-images-from-controller)